# yairEO/tagify same event when tag added on script load and on user added tag by himself

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

Im using *jquery* and nice library from github [yairEO/tagify](https://github.com/yairEO/tagify)

I need to separate two events when tag is added by user and when tag is added by script on load:

```
tagify.on('add', function(e, tagName){
    console.log('added', tagName)
});
```

It is neccesary to ajax update, delete tags and add new. When I use javascript above i have log from console on load page and on tag add.

Need help ;)

Comment: No event is being fired when Tagify is first gets initialized with an initial value (set on the input itself). If Tags are being added, by your script, **after** the  initialization, they will be an `add` event fired

Answer (score 2):

I got my own solution.
Its not perfect but it work well !
(after pick tag from dropdown)

```
tagify.on('add', function(e){
    if(tagify.listeners.dropdown){
        var tag_id = e.detail.data.code;
        //do my code
    }
});
```